# relations between Bessel functions J0 and K0 (to find the Green's function for the 2D screened Poisson equation)

Tags: bessel-functions, greens-function

I'm trying to find the Green's function for the screened Poisson equation in two dimensions, i.e. the $G(\mathbf{r})$ that solves
$$(\nabla^2-1/\rho^2) G(\mathbf{r}) = \delta(\mathbf{r}), \qquad \mathbf{r}\in\mathbb{R}^2,$$
via Fourier transform methods. Everything is fine except for the final integral in the inverse transform, which is over the radius $k$ in polar coordinates.

Essentially my question is: "how do you do the last step on the last line of [the relevant wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screened_Poisson_equation)?" which is:
$$\int_0^\infty dk\frac{k}{k^2+1/\rho^2}J_0(kr) = K_0(r/\rho).$$

I can't find anywhere such a relation between the 0th-order Bessel function of the first kind $J_0(x)$ and the 0th order modified Bessel function of the second kind $K_0(x)$, except on that particular wikipedia page.

Could someone point me to a reputable reference for this integral relation, or otherwise indicate how I might show this result? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the integral,
$$ I:=\int_0^\infty  \frac{x}{x^2+q^2} \text{J}_0(x\,r)\ dx $$
insert the well-known integral
$$  \frac{x}{x^2+q^2} = \int_0^\infty  e^{-x\,u}\cos{(q\ u)} \ du.$$
Switch integrations.  Many integral tables have
$$ \int_0^\infty  e^{-x\,u} \text{J}_0(x\,r)\ dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+u^2}}. $$
Scale and use Digital Library of Mathematical Functions 10.32.6,
$$ \text{K}_0(w)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos{(w \ t)}}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} dt.$$
You'll find  $I=\text{K}_0(r\ q), $ equivalent to your question with $q=1/\rho.$  For more rigor, justify the interchange of integrations.

Comment: Thanks! Justifying the exchange of integrations is just by saying that $x$ and $u$ are independent and the limits on neither integral depend on the other variable, right? Or am I missing something subtle?